# $\int\cos^a xdx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Related to one of my earlier questions, I have an integral that I've found after a few substitutions reduces to

$$\int f(x)g(x)dx$$

where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ both have the form

$$\sum_{i=1}^nk_i\cos^{a_i}x,k_i\in\mathbb{R},a_i\in\mathbb{Z}$$

Therefore, the product should be in the same form, although there are potentially a lot of terms.  I was hoping to write a program to perform the multiplication and, hopefully, evaluate the definite integral with the appropriate bounds.  Towards this end, I was hoping I could come up with a closed form for the integral

$$\int\cos^axdx$$
  I've found recursive formulas in a couple places and I've tried Wolfram, but, [well...](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20cos%5En%20x%20dx)

I attempted to divide the problem into even and odd cases.  For the odd case,

$$\int\cos^{2m+1}xdx=\int(1-\sin^2x)^m\cos xdx=\int(1-u^2)^mdu$$

I could use the binomial theorem here for $m>0$, but not sure what I could do for negative $m$.

Even case is similar.

$$\int\cos^{2m}xdx=\sec^{-2m}xdx=\int(1+\tan^2x)^{-m-1}\sec^2xdx=\int(1+u^2)^{-m-1}du$$

Here, negative $m$ is easier to work with than positive.  Any advice?  Are the recursive formulas really the way to go?

Comment: I think that the problem is different depending if "a" is or not an integer. Could you clarify ? If "a" is an integer, Cos[x]^a can always be represented as a linear combinations of cosines of multiple angles.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Sorry if it wasn't clear.  All exponents are integer, though not necessarily positive.

Comment: For positive integer values of the exponents look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_identities (search for power-reduction formula)

Comment: For negative values of the exponent, there is clearly two families of results dependy on m odd or even. The formulas are not complex ... but I have not been able to find the general formula.

Comment: See [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals).